# Order 5 elements at a time in a column according to their lexicographical order

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hy all, I want to order a column for each group of  5 elements at time.
I have a data frame like this:

```
Col1 Col2  Col3
1    data   abcd
2    data2  cda
3    data3  dcv
4    data4  cvda
5    data5  b
6    data6  abcd
7    data7  dcv
8    data8  cda
9    data9  cvda
10   data10 b
```

I would something like this:

```
Col1 Col2  Col3
1    data   abcd
2    data5  b 
3    data2  cda 
4    data4  cvda
5    data3  dcv
6    data6  abcd
7    data10 b
8    data8  cda
9    data9  cvda
10   data7  dcv
```

I want for each group of 5 elements in col3 their lexicographical order.
How can I obtain this result?

Answer (score 2):

Faster `groupby` with `sort_values` solution is sorting by `2` columns, here is another column created by integer division by `5`:

```
a = np.arange(len(df))
df = (df.assign(new = a // 5)
        .sort_values(['new','Col3'], ignore_index=True)
        .drop('new', axis=1)
        .assign(Col1 = a + 1))
print (df)
   Col1    Col2  Col3
0     1    data  abcd
1     2   data5     b
2     3   data2   cda
3     4   data4  cvda
4     5   data3   dcv
5     6   data6  abcd
6     7  data10     b
7     8   data8   cda
8     9   data9  cvda
9    10   data7   dcv
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```py
print(
    df.groupby(df.index // 5)
    .apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("Col3"))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Prints:

```
   Col1    Col2  Col3
0     1    data  abcd
1     5   data5     b
2     2   data2   cda
3     4   data4  cvda
4     3   data3   dcv
5     6   data6  abcd
6    10  data10     b
7     8   data8   cda
8     9   data9  cvda
9     7   data7   dcv
```

Comment: Ya, it is slowier, so I dont prefer ;)